# “If I am to die, I shall have to have a say in it."

Tags: meaning

In this sentence,

> If I am to die, I shall have to have a say in it.

Can someone explain what "I shall have to have a say in it" means?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the the speaker believes they must have some sort of control over or input in how/when they die. It essentially means they plan to die on their own terms.

"a say in __" means that someone/something's input or voice will matter or be considered in the matter of ___